Functionals on Hilbert $C^*$-modules are completely bounded
It is well know that a functional on a $C^* $-algebra is completely bounded if and only if it is bounded in which case their norms coincide. My wish is to know if the same holds for Hilbert $C^* $-modules.
Let $A$ be a (unital) $C^* $-algebra and $\mathcal{F}$ a right Hilbert $A$-module. By a functional on $\mathcal{F}$ I mean a linear map $\phi_a: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow A $ associated to an element $a \in \mathcal{F}$ given by
$$
\phi_a(b) = \langle a, b \rangle_A.
$$

Is $\phi_a$ necessarily completely bounded and does it verify $\|\phi_a\|_{\text{cb}} = \|\phi_a\| \leq \|a\|$ ?

I know this to be true if $\mathcal{F}$ was an $A$-bimodule and $\phi_a$ was an $A$-bimodular map (which is not in general).
Specific case 1: Let $1 \in A \subseteq B $ be unital $C^* $-algebras and $E: B \rightarrow A$ a conditional expectation. We can view $B$ as a right pre-Hilbert $A$-module with action given by right multiplication and by defining for $a,b \in B$
$$
\langle a,b \rangle_A := E(a^*b).
$$
By separation and completion with respect to the induced norm we obtain a Hilbert $A$-module which is denoted by $L^2(B,E)$.

If $a \in L^2(B,E)$ is the functional $\phi_a = \langle a,\cdot \rangle_A: L^2(B,E) \rightarrow A$ completely bounded?

Observe that in this case $L^2(B,E)$ is an $A$-bimodule (both actions are given by multiplication), however $ \langle a,\cdot \rangle  $ is not $A$-bimodular in general.
Specific case 2: Suppose $\mathcal{F} = A$ meaning we view $A$ as an right $A$-module over itself (by mulitplication) then $\langle a,b \rangle_A = a^*b$. Is the functional $\phi_a = \langle a,\cdot \rangle$ completely bounded?
Response: I think it is, the proof boils down to showing that the diagonal matrix $\text{diag}_n(a^*) \in M_n(A)$ satisfies $\|\text{diag}_n(a)\|_{M_n(A)} = \|a^*\| = \|a\|$.

Is the above correct? If so, then it would also solve Case 1 since $E$ is completely positive and so $b \mapsto E(a^*b)$ is the composition of completely bounded maps.


Your argument in specific case $2$ is correct.

For the general question, I’m not familiar enough with Hilbert $C^\ast$-modules. Just wondering, how is the operator space structure on a Hilbert $C^\ast$-module defined? (As that is needed to talk about complete boundedness.) Is it just $|(a_{ij}){ij}|{M_n(F)} = |(\sum_k \langle a_{ki}, a_{kj} \rangle){ij}|{M_n(A)}^{1/2}$?

@DavidGao Yes, that's the canonical operator space structure. Maybe a nicer way to think of it is that $M_n(F)$ is a Hilbert $M_n(A)$-module (with the obvious inner product) and the norm on $M_n(F)$ is that induced by the inner product. The amplifications of the function $\phi_a$ are then the maps $\langle \mathrm{diag}(a),\cdot\rangle_{M_n(A)}$, and the problem essentially boils down to specific case 2 from the question.

Another approach (more in line with concrete operator spaces) uses the fact that for every concrete $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ and every Hilbert $A$-module $F$ there exists a canonical embedding $\iota$ of $F$ into the bounded operators on a Hilbert space such that $\iota(a)^\ast \iota(b)=\langle a,b\rangle_A$ (and $\iota$ is completely isometric for the operator space structure from the previous comment). Then the problem really is a special case of specific case 2 from the question.

@MaoWao I see thank you a lot!
